# What are the requirements for crowns in Fotonica?

Tags: fotonica

What are the requirements to get crowns for each level in [Fotonica](http://www.fotonica-game.com/)? Is it ball-based or entirely score-based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more than 10,000 points in a level or more than 25,000 in the endless level.